# Replacing the first Characters in a string after Each occurrence of "blank space"

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2013

I have a data base consists of full names (first mid and last name)
I have created a text box and a search button. 
i want to customize my text box To both Replace each " " (blank space) with  "*" after writing the search word & To replace Letter  "A" & "B" if they are the first character of the first mid or last name With ""(blank) or to remove them.

My Code works with replacing " "(blank space) with "*" but only removes the first Character of the first name if its "a" or "b" i want it to Continue doing that with the mid and last name.

```
enter code here
Private Sub Name_AfterUpdate()

Me!Name = Replace(Me!Name, " ", "*")
If Left(Me!Name, 1) = "A" Or Left(Me!Name, 1) = "B" Then
Me!Name = mid(Me!Name, 2)
End if
End sub
```

Comment: Can you use REGEX? I can construct ad show you a regex that would do this

Comment: No i can't :( .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the following approach:

```
Me!Name = "*" & Replace(Trim(Me!Name), " ", "*")
Me!Name = Replace(Me!Name, "*A", "*")
Me!Name = Replace(Me!Name, "*B", "*")
Me!Name = Mid(Me!Name, 2)
```

Comment: Yes but this will Replace all The A's And B's in the whole string , i just want to replace the first character , Example if i search for "ANGELINA ARMANY" i want it to bring back Ngelina RMANY not  *NGELINA***RM*NY

Comment: Did you try it?

Comment: Sorry after i tried it really works Thanks. Many thanks sorry for My 1st reply i didn't imagine it would work.